# How to handle Swipe and Click event in the same cardview - Android

Tags: java, android, click, swipe, cardview

I am working on a android app, which has card swiping functionality like Tinder. In each cards, I'm having a `imageview`, which on click, opens in full screen. My problem is when I try to swipe, the image view considers it as a click event and opens the image in full screen.

I'm having my code for `imageview` `onclick` in the card swipe adapter and the code for swipe in the main activity that uses the card swipe adapter. How can I restrict the child view from consuming the parent's event?

Comment: Are you using GestureDetector for swipe? Can you post the swipe code?

Comment: typically, a `return true` consumes the event, and same request as Bryan, where's the code for your gesture?

Comment: @BryanDunlap  I am using https://github.com/aaronbond/Swipe-Deck card views.